# Compose SQL Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I'm trying to implement a simple search engine on a Rails5 app.

Basically, I have several fields in a form and I need to fetch all the records that match all the input values. Note that all values are optional.

The values I can search for are `name`, `description`, `created_at`.

My idea is to create a clause for each value and then join them together.

```
class EmployeeSearch < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'employees'


  def results
    # MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
  end

 private

 def table
  Employee.arel_table
 end

 def name_condition 
  table[:name].eq(name)
 end

def description_condition
  table[:description].matches("%#{description}%") unless description.blank?
 end

def created_at_condition
 ...
end

end
```

`EmployeeSearch.new(name: 'John Doe', created_at: '01/01/2010')`

Now, How can I loop through all the conditions in `results` and chain each one on a `where` clause?

I was thinking something like

```
methods.grep(/_condition$/).map { |c| where(send(c)) }
```

or similar but I cannot make it work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What was missing from my solution was returning the relation.
`methods.grep(/_condition$/).inject(Employee) do |klass, condition|
      klass = klass.where(send(condition))
    end`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use chaining for this. I would put your filter fields in an array, for example `filter[name]`

Then you could do something like this:

```
@employees = Employee
if params[:filter]
  params[:filter].each do |f_name, f_value|
    next if f_value.blank?
    @employees = @employees.where(f_name => f_value)
  end
end
```

Sorry couldn't test it, but should work

Comment: Unfortunately, the `where` clause are always the same. Something is a simple equal, sometimes I need to match a regexp, something I need to check if the value is in range. What I wish to do is to define N `_condition` methods and loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

Your example would work but you need to place the `where` clause on the association:

```
methods.grep(/_condition$/).each do |condition|
  association = association.where(send(condition))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is `association`? BTW The code above does not work.

Comment: Association is a scope you are trying to apply filters on. For example `Employee.all`

Comment: Ok. Anyway I have solved it as described in my comment above. Have a good 1